# Problem with floating window and zindex applied

Tags: javascript, css

I have two frames - such as frame1 and frame2
I am having a button in frame2, and a floating window will appear while click on it. 
 The **problem** is, while clicking the button in frame2, the floating window is appears partially behind the frame1. I need to show the floating window which should float on both the frame1 and frame2. I gave poistion:absoulte and zindex for this.. But its not working. 
 Please get me a solution for this.. 
Thanks 

Praveen J

Answer (score 0):

Frames are essentially two different websites in one. Zindex won't help you. It can't be done. That being said, different browsers will behave differently

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible for framed content to break out of the frame it's displayed in. No matter what CSS positioning you use, the div will always stay inside it's frame.

There are a few alternative options you might want to consider:

- Use iframes instead of frames, and display the 'floating window' on the parent (outside the iframes)
- Instead of a CSS-positioned 'fake' popup window, open a real window with [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/met_win_open.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the html for the floating window at the bottom of the html page, right before the  tag. Since the browser renders them from top to bottom, the last element rendered should automaticely be placed on top.

I've had some problems with Z-index myself before, I don't really know why it doesn't always work as you would expect it would.

**Update:**
I though he meant 'divs' with 'frames'